# Can't navigate outside index.html (thymeleaf+springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using springboot + thymeleaf to create a simple web site.

This is my project, Maven like created with STS :

[image]

`CSS` folder is repeated but isn't a problem I guess. When I run it as SpringBoot application all works fine. My index.html page is shown and both `CSS`, `JS` work perfectly.
The problem appear when I try to visit a new page (`hello.html`) following a `th:href` in `index.html`.
This is html section :

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> //For thymeleaf
<head> 
    <title> X BIG DEALS </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  
      href="/css/index/index.css" th:href="@{/css/index/index.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/
bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/
iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> //just bootstrap
    </head>

<header id="HD" class="header">
        <a class="logo">X4ALL</a>
        <div class="header-right">
            <a th:href="@{/hello}" id = "HELLO" class="active">Hello</a> //PROBLEM HERE I SUPPOSE
        </div>
    </header>
```

When I click this link a TomCat error page is shown with description : `Error 404 - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.`

Then I checked spring and found this error :

```
2021-11-17 14:28:19.694 ERROR 90008 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

So there's an error with `Thymeleaf` but I don't know very well how to move, this is `HelloController`  :

```
package it.uniroma3.siw.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
public class HelloController  {
    @RequestMapping(value= "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "hello" ;
    }
}
```

I also tried to return hello.html but nothing changed.
Before running as Springboot App I did a `Maven Clean` and `Maven Install`.

Maybe helps, `application.properties` :

```
#==================================
# = Datasource configuration
#==================================
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.sql.init.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/products
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
#==================================
# = Webserver configuration
#==================================
server.port= 8080
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.include-stacktrace=always

#==================================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
#==================================
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.context-path=/

#==================================
# = Logging configuration
#==================================
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.it.uniroma3.siw.spring=DEBUG

#==================================
# = Misc configuration
#==================================
spring.messages.basename=messages/message
##==================================
# = Security configuration
#==================================
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

P.S. : I think there are no controllers that handle `index.html` because at the beginning I didn't create one and however default page was already `index.html` and it worked. Then I created a `MainController` to accept `"/"` but I don't think it works.

Application file :

```
package it.uniroma3.siw.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.uniroma3.siw.*")
public class ProgettoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProgettoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: quick comment but i believe you dont need to specify .html in the controller when you return a thymeleaf resource. spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html takes care of that so just return "hello"

Comment: I already tried both, I wrote bad. Editing soon

Comment: shouldnt /hello be inside ''?  like that ``<a th:href="@{'/hello'}" />``

Comment: @Szprota21 I tried but nothing

Comment: Do you have @ComponentScan set up inside your Application class?

Comment: @Szprota21 No I only have "@SpringBootApplication"

public class ProgettoApplication {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ProgettoApplication.class, args);
 }


}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.uniroma3.siw.*")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field loginValidator in it.uniroma3.siw.controller.LoginController required a bean of type 'it.uniroma3.siw.validator.LoginValidator' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'it.uniroma3.siw.validator.LoginValidator' in your configuration.

Comment: so there is something wrong with your loginController

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misconfigured your application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
```

Anyway  I think you can remove all configuration related with thymeleaf in  application.properties as Spring Boot by default takes care of that!

Comment: Also, @ComponentScan is probably also missing, so Spring doesn't know where to look up for controllers. Do you have a main class?

Comment: Yes I have one, it's also flagged as @SpringBootApplication

Comment: So should I delete all these properties?

Comment: Yes you can, Spring boot will do that for you. You should put properties only if you intend to override the default spring configurations

Comment: @FinleyAdams also move the main class to the base package: it.uniroma3.siw, otherwise Spring won't look for beans in all the packages.

Answer (score 0):

To render a new page, you can setup a menu in a layout.html with links such as:

```
<header th:fragment="site-header">
    <a href="index.html" th:href="@{/}"></a>
    <a href="#" style="color: white" th:href="@{/}">Home</a>
    <a href="#" style="color: white" th:href="@{/add}">Add Items</a>
    <a href="#"  style="color: white" th:href="@{/items}">Get Items</a>
</header>
```

THis give you a menu like:

[image]

Now setup a corresponding controller method that correspond to each link. For example the Get Items invokes this controller method:

```
 @GetMapping("/add")
    fun designer(): String? {
        return "add"
    }
```

This will being up the add.html page under templates:

[image]

You can use a class like this with the **@SpringBootApplication** so Spring finds the main class.

```
package com.example;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class SecureWebApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SpringApplication.run(SecureWebApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is a massive improvement over the old Spring MVC framework where you had to mess around with a lot of config files. More details here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

That is how you can navigate pages in a Spring BOOT app.

Comment: href="#" or the name of the page, for example <a href="item.html"  style="color: white" th:href="@{/items}">Get Items</a>

Comment: See update thread on your question about how Spring finds the main class.

Comment: I added the Application file

Answer (score 0):

Solved creating a new project and copy-paste the old one.